# Text decoration below path

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

This should be a very simple question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[-stealth,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={this way}}}](0,0)to[bend right=45] (2,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I want the text to be below the line, not above. Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The placement of a decoration relative to the path can be controlled with the `raise` key. A positive value shifts the decoration to the left of the path direction, and a negative value shifts it to the right. Thus, for your example, a negative value is needed. In the example below I've added the key `raise=-8pt` to the decoration.

More information can be found in the [TikZ/PGF manual on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). Chapter 24 (pp. 351--357) covers `decorations` and the `raise` key is described on p. 356.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[-stealth,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={this way},raise=-8pt}}](0,0)to[bend right=45] (2,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could also guide the OP to the page 355-356 of the `pgfmanual` v3.00 and make reference to the info given there.

Comment: @azetina: Good suggestion. I have updated the answer.

Comment: This affects the kerning of the text. Is there an alternative which does not?