# TikZ path decoration: text below path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

I would like to place a text *below* a given path in TikZ, see "label b" in the screenshots below.

Unfortunately I have failed to find a `below` key for path decorations in the documentation.

So instead I have tried to measure the height of the text, negate it and raise the decoration by that amount.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\radius}{2}
    \coordinate (cs-center);

    \draw (cs-center) circle (\radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(  0 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(120 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(240 + 180 : \radius);


    \newcommand{\labelraise}{1pt}
    \path[decorate, decoration={text along path, text=label a, text align=center, raise=\labelraise}] (cs-center) ++(180 : \radius) arc (180 : 300 : \radius);

    \newlength{\labelheight}
    \settoheight{\labelheight}{l}
    \path[decorate,decoration={text along path, text=label b, text align=center, raise=-\labelheight-\labelraise}] (cs-center) ++(180 : \radius) arc (180 : 60 : \radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But `\settoheight` does not seems to work inside of the tikzpicture. `\labelheight` is set to zero.
(So "label b" is lowered by the 1pt of `\labelraise` only.)

[image]

If I try to raise it by a (not satisfying) hardcoded `-1em` the characters of the label move together (the *b* and the *e* are even touching each other):

[image]

So I have tried to change the path itself, decreasing the radius by 1em, but that results in a `! Dimension too large.`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\radius}{2}
    \coordinate (cs-center);

    \draw (cs-center) circle (\radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(  0 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(120 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(240 + 180 : \radius);


    \newcommand{\labelraise}{1pt}
    \path[decorate, decoration={text along path, text=label a, text align=center, raise=\labelraise}] (cs-center) ++(180 : \radius) arc (180 : 300 : \radius);

    \newlength{\labelheight}
    %\settoheight{\labelheight}{l} % this does not work
    \setlength{\labelheight}{1em}
    \newcommand{\textradius}{\radius-\labelheight}
    \path[decorate,decoration={text along path, text=label b, text align=center, raise=-\labelraise}] (cs-center) ++(180 : \textradius) arc (180 : 60 : \textradius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

I have seen the question [Text decoration below path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198192/120953) but the only answer there just suggests a hardcoded `raise` which has the above shown problems.

How can I place a text below a path so that I do not need to change hardcoded numbers if I want to change the font size and where the characters have a natural distance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ti*k*Z it is very simple to compute the height of a character, e.g. `height("l")`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\radius}{2}
    \coordinate (cs-center);

    \draw (cs-center) circle (\radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(  0 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(120 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(240 + 180 : \radius);


    \newcommand{\labelraise}{1pt}
    \path[decorate, decoration={text along path, text=label a, text align=center, raise=\labelraise}] (cs-center) ++(180 : \radius) arc (180 : 300 : \radius);

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\labelheight}{height("l")}
    \path[decorate,decoration={text along path, text=label b, text align=center,
    raise=-\labelraise-\labelheight}] (cs-center) ++(180 : \radius) arc (180 : 60 : \radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One way to adjust the space between the characters is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\radius}{2}
    \coordinate (cs-center);

    \draw (cs-center) circle (\radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(  0 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(120 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(240 + 180 : \radius);


    \newcommand{\labelraise}{1pt}
    \path[decorate,decoration={text effects along path, text={label a}, 
    raise=\labelraise, text align=center,
    text effects/every character/.style={text along path,inner xsep=0.1pt}}] (cs-center) ++(180 : \radius) arc (180 : 300 : \radius);

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\labelheight}{height("l")}
    \path[decorate,decoration={text effects along path, text={label b}, 
    raise=-\labelraise-\labelheight, text align=center,
    text effects/every character/.style={text along path,inner xsep=0.3pt}}] (cs-center) ++(180 : \radius) arc (180 : 60 : \radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An arguably cleaner solution is to just shift the second path:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\radius}{2}
    \coordinate (cs-center);

    \draw (cs-center) circle (\radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(  0 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(120 + 180 : \radius);
    \draw (cs-center) -- ++(240 + 180 : \radius);


    \newcommand{\labelraise}{1pt}
    \path[decorate, decoration={text along path, text=label a, text align=center, raise=\labelraise}] (cs-center) ++(180 : \radius) arc (180 : 300 : \radius);

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newradius}{\radius*1cm-\labelraise-height("l")}
    \path[decorate,decoration={text along path, text=label b, text align=center}] 
    (cs-center) ++(180 : {\newradius*1pt}) arc (180 : 60 : {\newradius*1pt});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `\pgfmathsetmacro{\labelheight}{height("l")}`. that's a good step forward. do you also have an idea how to increase the distance between the characters so that *b* and *e* don't touch each other?

Comment: @jakun I added one possibility. Another possibility would be to draw a path parallel to the one you chose and to put the text there.